# Apps Script - search all file names within a folder and return the largest number within the file name string to generate next jobcode

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When my company sends an estimate we currently create a new file from a template that's this huge sheets book with a ton of individual tools and indexed databases. I'm currently trying to trim it way down and make it a more automated and forward-facing experience.

My first roadblock is this:

Each file is named "1234 JobName clientName" I don't want people to have to type everything in multiple times and open a folder to see what the next job code is supposed to be.

I have a button on the new template that runs my (currently not working) script to look at the first 4-5 characters of all the files in a specific folder, take the highest number job code +1 and prefix the current book's filename with that new 5 digit jobcode.

I'm new at apps script, but have some javascript in my past. Fairly advanced sheets user.

Thanks ahead of time!

Here's my current code that simply throws a predetermined string inside of a cell. I commented out the start of a while loop I was going to use to try and get all the file names into an array before searching the string of each one but I was grasping at straws here.

```
function jobCodeButton() {
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById('1oQIF7aDH7Yj421aP85Z_unjPqhXfhxb8').getFiles();
  Logger.log(files);
 // while (files.startsWith()) {
 //   const
 // }

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MAIN").getRange('C2:C2').setValue("XXXXX");
}
```

Comment: Why don't/can't you track the jobcode from the spreadsheet rather than trying to find a needle in a haystack via file names?

Comment: Just considering options... have you considered importing the file names into a sheet/spreadsheet, sorting by name, and taking the prefix from the top-most file?

Comment: @Tedinoz Each job gets its own spreadsheet from a master template. There's already a few hundred. That's why it's a pain to be on the phone with a client trying to get a new bid going and have to open a bunch of tabs and such.

Comment: @Tedinoz That's not a bad suggestion. I'm comfortable with sheets so sorting wouldn't be an issue in that environment... Ultimately I'd like that all to happen in an array so I don't have more sheets open, but i think that's the easy button... I'll play around with it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tedinoz So here's where I'm stuck.

I got logger to list the file names and how many files there are. Basically, I have an array of filenames and a while loop iteration counter.
Currently stuck trying to figure out how to setValues() in my sheet. the range seems to never match the length of the array

So the question is: How to I use setValues() when I never know the exact size of my two dimensional range?

Comment: `How to I use setValues() when I never know the exact size of my two dimensional range?` I've posted an answer - "push" the file names onto an array, then get the length of the array = number of "rows".

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateSheetList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "fileList"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  var folderID = "1SO1Te6qvPv_mq_TZGXxfRtA1EYkUb1nD"
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)
  var files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")
  
  var tempArray =[]
  var fileArray = []
  while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();

  tempArray.push([file.getName()])
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
  //Logger.log("number of files "+tempArray.length)
  sheet.getRange(1,1,tempArray.length).setValues(tempArray)
  sheet.sort(1, true);
}
```